# pass query string variables without refresh page

Tags: php, javascript, html

My question is that how to pass query string variables on same page without refreshing the page in  php? My code is given below:

```
<a href="?id=1&pid=2"><img src="a.jpg"></a>

<?php
$a = $_GET['id'];
$b = $_GET['pid'];
?>
```

Please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: you can send ajax request!

Comment: If you have a problem, [jquery](http://www.jquery.com) will fix it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<meta name="" content="">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#image_id").click(function(){
            var dataString = 'a=10&b=20';
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'foo.php',
                data:dataString,
                success:function(data) {
                    if(data=="Something") {
                        // Do Something
                    } else {
                        // Do Something
                    }   
                }           
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <img id="image_id" src="images/bg.jpg" />
</body>
</html>
```

Then in the 'foo.php' page do this

```
if(isset($_POST['a'])) {
   // DO SOMETHING

}
```

Remember the things that you want to send to the 'data' of

```
success:function(data)
```

must be echoed out in the foo.php page

Answer (score 0):

**You can't.**

PHP requires execution on the server and so you'd have to either use AJAX and update your page accordingly, or just refresh your page.

Comment: tell me which kind of method i would apply in ajax to do this?

Answer (score 0):

**You can** by sending an AJAX request to the server. Ajax is a way to send asynchronous request via Javascript. Notice that jQuery has a good [library](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) about it.

Comment: Iframes are also a solution

Answer (score 0):

Use [jquery](http://jquery.com/) to resolve this. By using the $.ajax in jquery you can do the stuff you need without page refresh.

Comment: when i click the img tag page refresh even i call ajax. please write some code as example so i can understand it more clearly..